# Secure a particular command with Password before executing it

Tags: command-line, password

Here I have a question can we **secure a "command" with a "PASSWORD"**

for example lets say if I type

> `pwd`

command on terminal, Linux should prompt for a password even I am the Admin of the system.

OR can we force user to prefix `sudo` before a particular command on linux

Comment: `pwd` is a shell builtin ..., so I guess the answer is no.

Comment: Might this be an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?

Comment: Is this what you want ? :  isolating a user which can issue only a limited set of commands and to get more control over the system , he/she needs to get root access.

Comment: @pLumo ```pwd``` was example. I want to password protect: ```git push``` command.

Comment: I think you have the wrong setup ... Pushing to a git should be secured server-side, instead of pseudo-securing the client-side ...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to isolate a user in order to limit the set of commands that he/she can issue and in order to get more control over the system he/she needs to get the root access. To implement this, first you should make the [restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) the default shell for that user:

```bsh
usermod -s /bin/rbash user
```

And you can create a specific directory for that user to store the symlinks to the executables that you want to grant access to:

```bsh
mkdir /home/user/programs
```

Edit the user's `.bash_profile` file to limit the scope of the commands that the user can run:

```bsh
PATH=$HOME/programs  
export PATH
```

Create some symlinks (i.e, shortcuts from the Windows perspective):

```bsh
ls -s /bin/ls /home/user/programs/
ls -s /bin/date /home/user/programs/
ls -s /bin/uname /home/user/programs/
```

The last step is to prevent the user to actually modify the `.bash_profile` file's metadata:

```bsh
chattr +i /home/user/.bash_profile
```

This attribute makes the file immutable.

If you want to revert this, simply run:

```
chattr -i /home/user/.bash_profile
```

Don't forget to add the symlink to `/bin/su` to enable a user who knows the the root user's password to get root access. (To work, this also requires that password-based logins for the root account be enabled by setting a password for it.)

And don't forget *not* to add the user in the `sudo` group, or to remove the user from that group if present. If the user is a member of the `sudo` group, then the user can get root access via his/her own password!

Or another workaround is to not symlink the `/usr/bin/sudo` file at all.

[Original solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822)

If anybody has a better idea, I'm glad to hear.